# Where are 'CacheStatistics' in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm just trying to update a library to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5. Beside of other breaking changes, `org.springframework.boot.actuate.cache` and especially `CacheStatistics` is missing. Any idea, where I can find this (or something similar)?